# How to use regex for verifying multiple conditions in JAVA?

Tags: java, regex, string, unit-testing

I have a String as a input which has the below multiple conditions to pass.

It is a String  of length 8 and contains all numbers. Requirement is to 
method should return false if any of the below 4 conditions is true.

```
First two characters -  13, 24, 28

characters three and four - 55, 99

characters five and six - 20, 21 

last two characters - 42, 38, 09, 17, 66
```

How can I verify this using regex instead of spliting into 4 strings and checking.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: clearify string all digit or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your question, string is consist of digit or not, its not clear. If string consist of all digit then try with this::
`(^(13|24|28)\\d{6}$)|(^\\d{2}(55|99)\\d{4}$)|(^\\d{4}(20|21)\\d{2}$)|(^\\d{6}(42|38|09|17|66)$)`

```
String text = "12345678";
        if (text.matches("(^(13|24|28)\\d{6}$)|(^\\d{2}(55|99)\\d{4}$)|(^\\d{4}(20|21)\\d{2}$)|(^\\d{6}(42|38|09|17|66)$)")) {
            System.out.println("Inalid");
        } else if(text.matches("^\\d{8}$")){
            System.out.println("Valid");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid");
        }
```

Explaination:

- ^(13|24|28)\d{6}$) -- matches first two digit && \d{6} means next 6
  character is any digit..
- (^\d{2}(55|99)\d{4}$) -- \d{2} means first two any digit && matches
  3rd and 4th digit with condition..\d{4} mean last 4 character be any
  digit..

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DqnIiq/11) here to check match or unmatch...

Comment: Doesn't do the requirements of the question, e.g. question doesn't say the string is all digits.

Comment: @Andreas he said 8 letter string... and he match every  pair 2 digit. its common all digit. if not then `\\d` will be replace with `.`

Comment: If you want to interpret "8 letter string" as "8 digit string", you can, but you then have to say that in the answer, because that is an *assumption* you're making.

Comment: @Golam My case was anyway for all digits. Thanks.

Comment: @Thinker then is this answer ok for you?

Comment: Could you explain me a little bit like just this "(13|24|28)\\d{6}$)" ?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use match group, so `(a|b)` would match either on `a` or `b`.

So your regex expression would be something like

```
^((13|24|28).{6}|.{2}(55|99).{4}|.{4}(20|21).{2}|.{6}(42|38|09|17|66))$
```

Which you could use in java with the `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes.

```java
if (value.length() != 8) {
    return false;
} else {
    String patternString = "^((13|24|28).{6}|.{2}(55|99.).{4}|.{4}(20|21).{2}|.{6}(42|38|09|17|66))$";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(value);
    boolean matches = matcher.matches();

    return !matches;
}
```

About the length of the string, I don't see a good way to check that in a regular expression. So just check it with an if-else statement.

But make sure to only complie the pattern once if you need it multiple times.

Also for creating regular expression I would suggest using website like [regex101](https://regex101.com/) or [regexr](https://regexr.com/).

Comment: Doesn't do the requirements of the question. Read the question again: *"It is **8 letter** String and the method should return **false** if **any** of the below 4 conditions is **true**"*.

Comment: @Andreas yeah sorry about that. Corrected it.

Comment: Please stop the saracasm! :P

Comment: @Ackdari What is {6} {2} {4}|.{4} .{6}) in the pattern?

Comment: @Thinker I will give an example `a{6}` will match on six `a`s and `.` matches any character execept linebreak, so `.{6}` will match on six characters that are on one line

Comment: I highlighted the keywords for you: "should return **false**, if **any** condition is **true**". --- Examples where code fails: `13000000` returns *true*, should return *false* (since first condition is *true*). --- `00000000` returns *false*, should return *true* (since none of the conditions are *true*).

Comment: @Andreas for `13000000` `matches` will be true that is correct, but that is also why It stated _"`matches` will be true if any of the condistions is true so just return `!matches`"_. And for `00000000` it will be the other way around but still correct.

Comment: You should show that in the **code**. --- Doesn't make it work, though, because is fails for e.g. input `"xx"`.